# Multiframe indexing not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, templates, animate

Moving forward from this Question:
[Animateinline not working with \setbeamertemplate{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359390/animateinline-not-working-with-setbeamertemplate),
I modified the code to this MWE (Need not go back to see the previous question, it is kept as a reference):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Marburg}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop, begin={\begin{tikzpicture}\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (7,7);}, end={\end{tikzpicture}}]{6}
   \multiframe{10}{i=1+1}{
   \newframe
\node[anchor=south west] 
  at (0,-4) (anime)
  {\includegraphics[trim = 15mm 10mm 10mm 10mm,clip,width=0.5\textwidth]{md-angles-\i}};
}
\end{animateinline}
}
  \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{iitm_logo}}

\title[My Short Title]{My Long Title} 
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}%  
}
\author[{Vishnu}]{Vishnu} 
\institute[My Institute] 
{
Designation \\ 
}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\advance\textwidth2cm
\hsize\textwidth
\columnwidth\textwidth
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, I am getting error as:

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'md-angles-\i' not found.
```

The index '\i' over `multframes` does not seem to convert into a value. How do I get the values of i to be substituted instead of '\i' in the code?

Comment: Please reduce your example to the bare minimum. With no more than `animate` and `graphicx` packages loaded. And a simple`\includegraphics{md-angles-\i}` embedded in a `\multiframe{...}` loop. If the issue persists, than `animate` is to be blamed.

Comment: I have done the requisite edits, and the problem still seem to persist. Kindly have a look.

Comment: A further minimized example using a file sequence of mine works without problems. Why don't you use `\animategraphics` for numbered files? It can be placed into a TikZ node, if you want to move it around on your title page.

Comment: I have much expertise on tikz. It would be great if you could share the code.

Answer (score 1):

`\animategraphics` can be placed into a Ti*k*Z node, if an animation built from external files shall be inserted at an absolute position on the slide. There is no need for using `\includegraphics` inside a `tikzpicture` inside a `\multiframe` inside an `animateinline` environment. Also, cropping/trimming/resizing/scaling/clipping options of `\includegraphics` can be used with `\animategraphics`.

(Example using file sequence `exp_0.pdf` ... `exp_8.pdf`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (7,7);
    \node[anchor=south west] at (3,1) (anime) {
      \animategraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm,keepaspectratio,autoplay,loop]{6}{exp_}{0}{8}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
%  \begin{animateinline}[
%      autoplay, loop,
%      begin={\begin{tikzpicture}\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (7,7);},
%      end={\end{tikzpicture}}]{6}
%    \multiframe{9}{i=0+1}{
%      \node[anchor=south west] at (3,1) (anime) {\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=4cm,keepaspectratio]{exp_\i}};
%    }
%  \end{animateinline}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine. I am trying to add an overlay image over the animation(gif). So i need to make the image being overlaid also a part of the animation. As such i am using `animateinline` for the purpose.

Comment: I see. This, indeed, justifies the use of `animateinline`. So you can use the commented code part as a template, which is equivalent to the `\animategraphics` part. (Don't put a `\newframe` into a `\multiframe` body, as in your original code.)

Comment: It starts working. Eliminating the previous problem.
`! LaTeX Error: File 'md-angles-\i' not found.`
But now, i have a new problem
`! LaTeX Error: File 'md-angles-1.' not found`
See there is a period after the number